# are @types/node typings for RequestOptions incorrect?

Tags: typescript-typings

I found some code that is doing this:

```
        import * as url from "url";
        const { URL } = url;

        ...

        const url: URL = new URL(href)
        require("http").get({
            hostname : proxyUrl.hostname,
            protocol : proxyUrl.protocol,
            port     : proxyUrl.port,
            path     : url     // this is a WHATWG url object
        }, callback)
```

The code doesn't type-check as-is because http.get takes a `RequestOptions`, and the `path` key for `RequestOptions` is supposed to be of type `string`. However, the code works as-is (passing a URL object instead), and stops working if I change the value for the `path` key to `url.pathname`.

So are the @types/node typings incorrect or am I doing something wrong?

Using Node version 8 and @types/node 8.10.39.